# Тайминг между выводом элементов текстового массива. Unity

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d, тайминги

Столкнулась с такой неприятной проблемой. В общем, в unity для объектов Text прописала такой код:

```
{
public Text textUI;
private string text = "рандомный текст";

IEnumerator Start()
{
    yield return StartCoroutine(WaitAndPrint(118.0f));
    StartCoroutine("showText", text);
}

IEnumerator WaitAndPrint(float waitTime)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
}

IEnumerator showText(string text)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= text.Length)
    {
        textUI.text = text.Substring(0, i);
        i++;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
     }
    }
   }
```

Код рабочий. Данные строки позволяют выводить текст с задержкой символов и печать предложений выводится как бы вживую. Однако, прописывать такой код для каждого объекта (а их у меня свыше 30) только на одной сцене, слишком затратно по времени.
Помощь нужна конкретно вот в чем: как правильно прописать код, чтобы в массив GameObject для Text можно было для всех объектов текста разом прописать скрипт, который будет обращаться к элементам массива (через цикл) чтобы после вывода одного у меня плавно выводился следующий после определенного промежутка времени??? Если кто-то поможет с самим кодом, буду очень благодарна.

Comment: Опускать модификатор доступа `private` у функция не принято. Хотя он и идет по умолчанию, его принято прописывать явно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно вам следует получше обдумывать, как описать проблему. Чтобы понять, что вы хотите, пришлось перечитать трижды.

Скрипт текста:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Text))] // Обязываем иметь компонент Text
public class TextPrinter : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Text Text;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Text = GetComponent<Text>(); // Кэшируем
    }

    public IEnumerator PrintText(string text, int delay = 0)
    {
        Text.text = ""; // Устаналиваем пустую строку (можно опустить, если строка изначально гарантированно пустая)
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay); // Ждем

        for (int i = 0; i <= text.Length; i++) {
            Text.text = text.Substring(0, i); // Дописываем символ
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f); // Ждем
        }
    }
}
```

Скрипт для вывода текстов - исправил ваш

```
public class TextsController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TestPrinter[] Texts; // Массив со всеми текстами - указывать из инспектора
    private int delay = 1; / Время ожидания. Можно сделать константой, если это так

    /// <summary>
    /// Функция для вывода всех текстов по одному
    /// </summary>
    private IEnumerator ShowTextsOneByOne ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Texts.Length; i++) // Проходимся по текстам
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(Texts[i].PrintText("Here is text", delay)); // Вызываем при этом ожидая пока все не выведется
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Функция для вывода всех текстов сразу. Вы не просили – бонус.
    /// </summary>
    private void ShowAllTexts ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Texts.Length; i++)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Texts[i].PrintText("Here is text", delay));
        }
    }
}
```

Если остались вопросы — задавайте.
Если что-то не так понял — пишите.
Если ответ помог — примите.

Comment: Благодарю, добрый человек :)
Протестирую сегодня днем. 
(Извините за такую манеру объяснения, я над этим тоже поработаю)

Comment: Сегодня днем? Почти во всей России уже ночь) Хотя, знаете, программисты - они такие люди, для них ночь - день, а день - ночь:)))